# Why does rails raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid when .valid? called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

This seems to defeat the purpose of a `valid?` method.

I have a model as such:

```
class MonthlyUserUtility < ActiveRecord::Base
before_validation :month_ending_on_must_be_last_day_of_month
attr_accessible :month_ending_on   
def month_ending_on_must_be_last_day_of_month
 if self.month_ending_on.is_a?(Date)
   write_attribute(:month_ending_on, self.month_ending_on.end_of_month)
 elsif !self.month_ending_on.nil?
   errors.add(:month_ending_on, 'must be a valid datetime')
 end
end
end
```

Then I create an invalid instance as such

```
muu = MonthlyUserUtility.build({month_ending_on: false})
```

when I call `save` or `valid?` the validation runs but instead of returning false I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "f"
```

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: this actually has to do with the fact that the `month_ending_on` value is false. if I pass 'asdfasd' the validation works fine. No idea why this is but I changed the value in the validator as `self.month_ending_on = nil if self.month_ending_on == !!self.month_ending_on`. Fixes it but I have no idea why.

Comment: Which line does the error show ?

Comment: What does that mean, "when I call `save` of `valid?`?

Comment: `save` OR `valid?` - typo sorry fixed

Answer (score 0):

This can be because the model is not saved to the database yet before validation

Try replacing `before_validation` with `validate` (Note: not `validates`)